# Do people use Stack Overflow to market their products?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, self-promotion

Do people post questions about specific libraries or products to attempt to get people to answer with links to third party libraries?

I would imagine having a ton of links to your site on Stack Exchange couldn't be bad for business. An example would be asking a question about a method that is specific to a paid library; for example: [How to create json object in vbscript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456788/how-to-create-json-object-in-vbscript-file)

Comment: People ask for third party links but as asking for off-site resources is off-topic, they get closed and DVd. Links can change and off-site resource url can also change, making the answers invalid overtime

Comment: And people do post questions about specific libraries, as long as there is demand for it and questions are on-topic, they stay e.g. Take a look at third party component [SWRevealViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swrevealviewcontroller) for iOS here.  Also See which topics are [On-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) .

Comment: In the example question, how could I have best answered? Should I not have included the link to the library?

Comment: It is not my library, but it looks like it does cost $$

Actually to be fair it seemed to be the only legitimate result and obvious to anybody who could search google - which is why I suspected the question in the first place.

Comment: Well If I were you, I would have suggested the third party paid lib in comment, not as an answer. For answer, I'd have written a native answer which would not be dependent on any external resource.

Comment: Worth noting that external links have `rel="nofollow"` added, so the likes of Google shouldn't change rankings based on lots of links from SE to a particular site.

Comment: *[cough](http://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter)*

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, people do. No, it's generally not welcome.

There's an important distinction here though. As long as the problems are real problems, and the answer(s) aren't just blindly promoting a product, but actually solve the question at hand fair and evenhandedly, and as long as the question is useful and on topic, there is no problem here.

There are however companies that have employees post questions to deliberately seed their thinly veiled advertisements on the site, and those questions and answers are usually deleted by moderators or spam flags. There's a line between what's acceptable and what isn't, and it's not hard for companies to follow that line.

It's also supremely important to disclose potential affiliations you have. If I work for a company that makes lets say a third party library that *exactly* solves OP's problem, I could recommend it in the larger context of a complete answer that also mentions alternatives (although questions asking for tool recommendations are strictly off topic, the situation could arise where for instance someone is going through great lengths to do something that a library could solve in a minute) and addresses the question specifically, but I would have to absolutely disclose my affiliation.

Not disclosing product affiliation when recommending products can lead to being contacted by a moderator, having your post deleted or suspension.

Useful reading about this: [Help Center - How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)